# How to deploy with two DB on gcloud app engine?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy web application via gcloud to GCP App Engine.
This web application uses two difference databases - one DB is under "A" App Engine SQL and the other DB is under "B" App Engine SQL. Simply said it's run by difference instances now.

In Local DB was able to run the application well but when I try to compile my Java project it shown below error.

Based on the googling, I tried to figure out missing dependency and inserted in my pom.xml file but it was not working at all.

And if I point it to local DB from `application.properties` it was able to compile well. (The purpose of do compile is generate jar file to deploy my project.):

```
### *** Removed username/password and datasource url *** 

## ==============================================================
## = Datasource (Admin)
## ==============================================================
#admin.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
admin.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://google/url here
admin.datasource.username = 
admin.datasource.password = 
admin.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

## ==============================================================
## = Datasource 2 (API)
## ==============================================================
#api.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
api.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://google/url here
api.datasource.username = 
api.datasource.password = 
api.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

server.session.timeout = 600
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
server.port =8080
#server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Error when I did `mvn clean install`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project WorkspezAdmin: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\admin_Deploy\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

if I do `mvn clean and install`, I need to get jar file which can do deploy to GCP App Engine using gcloud. Is there anyone can give me related advice?

Thank you in advanced..

Additionally attached error

```
 The Google Cloud SQL API is not enabled for project [workspez-admin]. Please use the Google Developers Console to enable it: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin/overview?project=workspez-admin

Error creating bean with name 'adminEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/workspez/webconfig/AdminHibernateDbConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'adminEntityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/workspez/webconfig/AdminHibernateDbConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: **Could not create connection to database server.**
```

Comment: Please, add `gcloud` command that you use to deploy app.

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud SQL instances for your app on GCP?

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak Thank you for the comment sir! Yes i am using google cloud sql instance also(two instance from each different project) May I know exact mean of "add gcloud command that you sue to deploy app" ?Thanks!

Comment: I meant to ask how are you deploying your app? Do you use [`gcloud app deploy ...`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) command to deploy your app? If so, what the command is?

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak Thanks you for your reply again! The step is like below. Step1 : mvn clean install from main folder of my project. Step2 : copy created jar file and paste on appengine folder Step3. open cmd and run "gcloud app deploy"

Comment: I added permission for the testing app account to admin project and tried to compiled the project. And it worked! :) I am trying to deploy now. I will update the result again!

Comment: Run 'gcloud app deploy' but faced difference error message. I attached on my main question body

Comment: You need to visit https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin/overview?project=workspez-admin and enable Google Cloud SQL API for your project.

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak Thank you sir! I deployed well!! :) Have a nice day and appropriate your help so much again!